# Node app on heroku fails due to read only filesystem

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a very simple TypeScript app (build with Express.js) that runs on Node which I deploy to Heroku. I use both the node buildpack and `zidizei/heroku-buildpack-tsc`, the latter of which compiles the .ts to JavaScript at deploy time.

This has worked fine up to today when I tried to run a deploy. The deployment itself works fine but the app crashes subsequently at the point at which the launch script `node ./dist/server.js` is run. Logs here:

```
Sep 06 14:43:33 goodlord-bark app/web.1: $ node ./dist/server.js 
Sep 06 14:43:33 goodlord-bark heroku/web.1: Process exited with status 1 
Sep 06 14:43:33 goodlord-bark heroku/web.1: State changed from starting to crashed 
Sep 06 14:43:33 goodlord-bark app/web.1: error An unexpected error occurred: "EROFS: read-only file system, access '/usr/local/bin'". 
Sep 06 14:43:33 goodlord-bark app/web.1: info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/app/yarn-error.log".
```

At no point does any script or my app attempt to write to `/usr/local/bin` so I'm confused as to why this is happening. This error only occurred following a superficial change to the codebase and new deploy so it strikes me something has changed on Heroku's end but I can get to the bottom of it.

Rolling back to a previous deploy has kept my app running for the time being, but I'm currently unable to deploy any updates.

There is also no `/app/yarn-error.log` to examine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had similar issue on Heroku all of a sudden. Turns out the issue was introduced at yarn 1.0.0 and Heroku use the latest version by default. Here's a relevant heroku-buildpack-nodejs [issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/468).

Fixed by downgrading yarn in `engines` section of package.json:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "^7.10.1",
  "yarn": "0.27.5"
}
```

Comment: Crazy! - I had `"yarn": ">=0.27.0"` in my engines section. Clearly a bug somewhere. Changing it to "0.28.4" seems to have fixed it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Right, it broke with yarn 1.0.0 - so we've fixed it by forcing older version instead of latest which Heroku used by default.

Comment: Btw they now have yarn 1.0.1 out and it's marked as 'stable' on their website so "engines": {"yarn": "^1.0.1"} should work as well.